# Reading an image from remote ssh server into dask array

Tags: dask

Is this possible. Based on the documentation it looks like imread does not support anything but local file paths? If it is possible would anyone be so kind as to provide a code sample?

Cheers.

Comment: Its better you include more details about the problem, so users can answer you better

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/how-to/connect-to-remote-data.html),

The following remote services are well supported and tested against the main codebase:

- Local or Network File System: `file://` - the local file system, default in the absence of any protocol.
- Hadoop File System: `hdfs://` - Hadoop Distributed File System, for resilient, replicated files within a cluster. This uses PyArrow as the backend.
- Amazon S3: `s3://` - Amazon S3 remote binary store, often used with Amazon EC2, using the library s3fs.
- Google Cloud Storage: `gcs://` or `gs://` - Google Cloud Storage, typically used with Google Compute resource using gcsfs.
- Microsoft Azure Storage: `adl://`, `abfs://` or `az://` - Microsoft Azure Storage using adlfs.
- HTTP(s): `http://` or `https://` for reading data directly from HTTP web servers.

**Check above given documentation for more information**